# "Attach in New Window" button is not working in docker container at vscode

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

I'm connecting to remote server 'A' using ssh.
In server A, I made docker container 'B', attached to it and was doing my works in it.
In docker container B there are 2 folders, 'C' and 'D'. Now my window was opening C folder, and now I want to open folder D in new window. So I clicked 'Attach in New Window' button in container and it doesn't work.
What should I do to open new window of same B container?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by myself.
In container window, press `ctrl+K, O`. Then new window will be open.
+) It's not number 0, alphabet O.